# C# (Unity) Socket receives data overwrite?

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

Demo

https://github.com/mingchaoyan/chat

if you change SendMsg in BroadcastClient.cs to

```
void Send1(string inputString1) {
    Proto.BroadcastProto proto = new Proto.BroadcastProto();
    proto.userName = "Client";
    proto.stringMsg =inputString1;

    NetPacket p = new NetPacket();
    p.BeginWrite("OnRevMsg");
    p.WriteObject<Proto.BroadcastProto>(proto);
    p.EncodeHeader();

    networkManager.Send(p);
    inputString = "";
}

void SendMsg() {
    Send1 ("1");
    Send1 ("22");
    Send1 ("333");
    Send1 ("4444");
    Send1 ("55555");
    Send1 ("666666");
    Send1 ("7777777");
    Send1 ("88888888");

}
```

Yes just send more than one msgs at once, not send one receive one as before.

Then you will find Debug.log in OnRevMsg almost print

```
"88888888"
```

8 times.

I debuged the socket found the element of NetworkManager.packets(which is a queue) change to the new received every time when receiving a new msg!

Did I make some wrong with receiving data from socket?

Comment: Is there a matching EndWrite for the BeginWrite?

Comment: @RonBeyer No, I think that is enough

Answer (score 0):

I find the bug finally.

NetworkManager.cs, Buffer should be CopyTo a new NetPacket to avoid shadow copy.

```
public void AddPacket( NetPacket packet ) {
        lock (packets) {
            NetPacket p = new NetPacket();
            packet.bytes.CopyTo(p.bytes,0);
            p.bodyLength = packet.bodyLength;
            packets.Enqueue(p);
        }
    }
```

so I delete the demo.